# How should I understand this use of past and present tense in the same sentence?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

> 'Cause, baby, now we got bad blood
>   You know it *used* to be mad love
>   So take a look what **you've** done
>   'Cause, baby, now we got bad blood
>   BY TAYLOR SWIFT

Comment: I don't see it as one sentence... Seems like four sentences that simply don't have punctuation. Remember that grammar in poetry and song lyrics is very flexible, so it's very likely that you will run across poor language. Try not to use lyrics as reference.

Comment: What's wrong with using both past indefinite and present perfect in the same sentence?  "As a boy Bill was afraid of dark and has developed a coping mechanism."

Comment: thank you catija for your response but here i would like to ask you if you write this sentence with the proper usage of grammar how would you write ?

Comment: "So take a look what you've done" is ungrammatical.  It should be either "Look what you've done" or "Take a look at what you've done".

Comment: I see those sentences are grammatically correct. "We used to be madly in love (in the past), (but we are not in love anymore), so take a look at what you have done (to our love)."

Comment: @Meruemu: you have  corrected the lyrics. They do not say "So take a look *at* what you've done".

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+a+look+at+what%2Ctake+a+look+what%2Clook+what&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20look%20at%20what%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20look%20what%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clook%20what%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TRomano is that the way it should be? I am not a native speaker...

Comment: @Meruemu: Your way is correct.